# how to disable a button for 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, button

I want to disable a button for 30 seconds after the page is loaded (to prevent multiple clicking without even a try to watch the content). How can I do that?

```
<input class="button vote" type="submit" onClick="javascript: vote();" value="Vote for this story" />
```

Comment: Look a `setTimeout(function(){}, 30000)`

Comment: Why are you using a submit button with a javascript call? Is this button inside of a form? If so, the form could potentially be submitted before the function is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the attribute `disabled="disabled"` to your button.

Set a timeout:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(setDisabled, 30000);
}
```

Then define what to do after that timeout:

```
function setDisabled() {
    document.getElementById('yourButton').disabled = false;
}
```

You'll also need to add an id of 'yourButton' to your `input` tag.

Comment: doesn't work in chrome 60.

Answer (score 7):

If you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), this does the job:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("button").removeAttr("disabled");      
        }, 30000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqfKR/

Comment: When I use this, button disabled, its fine, but now form not submitting

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for setTimeout(). Give your input `id='votebutton' disabled="disabled"` and then include this at the bottom of your page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'><!--
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('votebutton').disabled = false;
    }, 30000);
</script>
```

Comment: The only thing I'd add is to use `window.onload` to make sure the page is fully loaded before trying to set the attribute.  Odds are that the page will be loaded within 30 seconds, but that's not something you can guarantee; if `votebutton` doesn't exist yet you'll get an error.